# Is it possible to create trigger in riak?

Tags: riak

I am using riak noSql database for development. I want to trigger action when record inserted in bucket. Is their any way to implement trigger in riak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. This is called a "commit hook" in Riak. According to [Using Commit Hooks](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/developing/usage/commit-hooks/),

> Pre- and post-commit hooks are functions that are invoked before or after an object has been written to Riak.

The link also contains details on how to write and configure commit hooks. You must be fluent in Erlang, the language Riak is written in, though.

There is also a section about hooks in the [Little Riak Book](http://www.littleriakbook.com/).